# How to get additional column from different table with Spring Data?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, hibernate-mapping

So lets imagine following situation. I have an entity such as this:

```
@Entity
public class Price {

    @Id
    private int id;

    @Column
    private int amount;

    private String currency;

}
```

And I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE currency (
id integer not null primary key,
name varchar
);
CREATE TABLE price (
    id integer not null primary key,
    amount integer,
    currency_id integer references currency(id)
);
```

I want to tell Spring that when I access Price.getCurrency() I want to have whatever is stored in column "name" of the "currency" table. In other words, I want to connect two tables in one entity.

I can make currency a separate class, annotate the property with @OneTo... and get it like price.getCurrency().getName(). But I don't want a separate class, I just need this specific column.

I tried adding it via @SecondaryTable annotation like this:

```
@SecondaryTable(name = "currency",
            pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "currency_id"))
```

But in this case Spring connect two tables by it's ids like this:

```
SELECT * FROM price LEFT JOIN price ON price.id = currency.id
```

And of course it is not working. So how do I do this? Is @SecondaryTable a correct way and if so how do I connect it through non-primary key column?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `@SecondaryTable`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "price")
@SecondaryTable(
    name = "currency",
    pkJoinColumns = {
        @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "currency_id")
    })
public class Price {

    @Id
    private int id;

    @Column
    private int amount;

    @Column(table = "currency", name = "name")
    private String currency;

}
```

Comment: I tried it like that and i get an error: "Unable to find column with logical name: currency_id in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(price) and its related supertables and secondary tables"

Comment: @admi are you 100% sure the column is a part of the `price` table in your schema? Your SQL obviously does not work

Comment: yes, I'm sure. I renamed entities and fields for easier explanation, so I just made up that SQL, but in my real db its 100% there, IDEA is even suggesting it for autocompletion there

Comment: @admi hmm, that's weird, I did the same thing in my project and it worked. Could you try again with curly braces?

Comment: it doesn't work. Does it mean something wrong with database or tables? My foreign key is set up correctly and I can retrieve data alright. Thanks anyway.